# Is it possible to pass two parameters via href?

Tags: php, html, href

I need to send two kinds of information from view to controller.

This is how my href looks like:

```
<a href="editBenefit/1}" class="btn blue">Modificar</a>
```

This is sending to my php function the parameter `1`, but let's say I have to send another parameter in that function, something like:

```
<a href="editBenefit/1/2}" class="btn blue">Modificar</a>
```

And my php function looks like:

```
function editBenefit($id, $option = '')
```

because parameter `2` won't always be sent. Like this, it's not working and I would like to know if this is possible or not in order to move on.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Yes, it's possible to send two parameters like: editBenefit/1/2 like @JohnConde said.

I was just having some lame mistake from the wrong template to the right function.

Comment: `editBenefit/1/2` is a valid URI so that should work. If it doesn't then it is a coding issue on the receiving end.

Comment: @JohnConde If I use editBenefit/1/2 then this error appears: Missing argument 2 for Admin::editBenefit()

Comment: It may be problem with url rewriting. In kohana there is bootstrap file, that determinate what url may look like.

Comment: Usually query strings are used to pass data via a URL, this might be a case where they are appropriate.

Comment: @zzzzBov I just need to send one flag

Comment: Passing parameters as paths may be not good practice, especially if you need to filter things. Query string parameters are the way to go. Google's webmaster blog published a piece on it just yesterday. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2014/02/faceted-navigation-best-and-5-of-worst.html

Comment: @JohnConde can you please turn your comments as the answer? so I can choose it.

Comment: @Limon It is now an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`editBenefit/1/2` is a valid URI so that should work. If it doesn't then it is a coding issue on the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

Limon

You should be able to create a variable array for $option with keys, which would pass two integer values.

Prior to your function, place something like this:

```
$option = array (
  value_1 = 1,
  value_2 = 2,
)

function editBenefit ($id, $option){

//your exciting function here

}
```

Comment: Don't want to create an array in the view. Just wanna pass few variables that requires no processing